# JQPlot: How to replot at different position

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

So I need to plot about 120 bar charts on my screen, so I do the following

```
var barPlot = $.jqplot(targetDiv, jsonBarObj, createBarChartOption(jsonLegendObj, jsonColsObj))
```

`targetDiv` is the id of different `div` on the page like `barDiv1`, `barDiv2` ...

In IE9, the browser hang very often. so my idea to store the JQPlot object to `barPlot` like above, then if not null, then `barPlot.replot()`. The problem I ran into is how do I specify the a new `target Id`. I try

```
barPlot.targetId = "#" + targetDiv;
```

but this does not work. Please help

**EDIT**: here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YX9wX/5/

**Click load, and if you alt+tab away and alt_tab back, you can see it hang on IE9, and hang until it finish all the drawing**

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle example?

Comment: I agree, with @Dom, we need a better test case scenario, since this is a rather specific question regarding optimization!

Comment: sorry I was so busy with other task at hand, that I could not do jsfiddle, doing it now

Comment: @Dom: I have add jsffidle: please have a look http://jsfiddle.net/YX9wX/5/

Comment: @Khez: I have add jsffidle: please have a look jsfiddle.net/YX9wX/5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best way to deal with IE hanging is to give the browser a short break after each plot:

```
$(function(){createPlot(1);});

function createPlot(plotIndex){
  var targetDiv = "barDiv" + plotIndex;
  // define jsonBarObj, jsonLegendObj & jsonColsObj here
  $.jqplot(targetDiv, jsonBarObj, createBarChartOption(jsonLegendObj, jsonColsObj))
  if(plotIndex < 20) setTimeout(function(){createPlot(++plotIndex);},1);
}
```

### Edit

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YX9wX/6)

Here's a full working html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://bitbucket.org/cleonello/jqplot/raw/81ec4eb933068c5009958b504feef3f27e1b1129/src/jquery.jqplot.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://bitbucket.org/cleonello/jqplot/raw/81ec4eb933068c5009958b504feef3f27e1b1129/src/plugins/jqplot.barRenderer.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://bitbucket.org/cleonello/jqplot/raw/b5a7796a9ebf/src/plugins/jqplot.cursor.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://bitbucket.org/cleonello/jqplot/raw/81ec4eb933068c5009958b504feef3f27e1b1129/src/plugins/jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://bitbucket.org/cleonello/jqplot/raw/81ec4eb933068c5009958b504feef3f27e1b1129/src/plugins/jqplot.canvasAxisLabelRenderer.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://bitbucket.org/cleonello/jqplot/raw/81ec4eb933068c5009958b504feef3f27e1b1129/src/plugins/jqplot.highlighter.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://bitbucket.org/cleonello/jqplot/raw/81ec4eb933068c5009958b504feef3f27e1b1129/src/plugins/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://bitbucket.org/cleonello/jqplot/raw/81ec4eb933068c5009958b504feef3f27e1b1129/src/plugins/jqplot.canvasAxisLabelRenderer.js"></script>

<style>

//jquery.jqplot.css

/*rules for the plot target div.  These will be cascaded down to all plot elements according to css rules*/
.jqplot-target {
    position: relative;
    color: #666666;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
/*    height: 300px;
    width: 400px;*/
}

/*rules applied to all axes*/
.jqplot-axis {
    font-size: 0.75em;
}

.jqplot-xaxis {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.jqplot-x2axis {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.jqplot-yaxis {
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.jqplot-y2axis, .jqplot-y3axis, .jqplot-y4axis, .jqplot-y5axis, .jqplot-y6axis, .jqplot-y7axis, .jqplot-y8axis, .jqplot-y9axis, .jqplot-yMidAxis {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

/*rules applied to all axis tick divs*/
.jqplot-axis-tick, .jqplot-xaxis-tick, .jqplot-yaxis-tick, .jqplot-x2axis-tick, .jqplot-y2axis-tick, .jqplot-y3axis-tick, .jqplot-y4axis-tick, .jqplot-y5axis-tick, .jqplot-y6axis-tick, .jqplot-y7axis-tick, .jqplot-y8axis-tick, .jqplot-y9axis-tick, .jqplot-yMidAxis-tick {
    position: absolute;
    white-space: pre;
}


.jqplot-xaxis-tick {
    top: 0px;
    /* initial position untill tick is drawn in proper place */
    left: 15px;
/*    padding-top: 10px;*/
    vertical-align: top;
}

.jqplot-x2axis-tick {
    bottom: 0px;
    /* initial position untill tick is drawn in proper place */
    left: 15px;
/*    padding-bottom: 10px;*/
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.jqplot-yaxis-tick {
    right: 0px;
    /* initial position untill tick is drawn in proper place */
    top: 15px;
/*    padding-right: 10px;*/
    text-align: right;
}

.jqplot-yaxis-tick.jqplot-breakTick {
    right: -20px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    padding:1px 5px 1px 5px;
/*    background-color: white;*/
    z-index: 2;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

.jqplot-y2axis-tick, .jqplot-y3axis-tick, .jqplot-y4axis-tick, .jqplot-y5axis-tick, .jqplot-y6axis-tick, .jqplot-y7axis-tick, .jqplot-y8axis-tick, .jqplot-y9axis-tick {
    left: 0px;
    /* initial position untill tick is drawn in proper place */
    top: 15px;
/*    padding-left: 10px;*/
/*    padding-right: 15px;*/
    text-align: left;
}

.jqplot-yMidAxis-tick {
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.jqplot-xaxis-label {
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 11pt;
    position: absolute;
}

.jqplot-x2axis-label {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 11pt;
    position: absolute;
}

.jqplot-yaxis-label {
    margin-right: 10px;
/*    text-align: center;*/
    font-size: 11pt;
    position: absolute;
}

.jqplot-yMidAxis-label {
    font-size: 11pt;
    position: absolute;
}

.jqplot-y2axis-label, .jqplot-y3axis-label, .jqplot-y4axis-label, .jqplot-y5axis-label, .jqplot-y6axis-label, .jqplot-y7axis-label, .jqplot-y8axis-label, .jqplot-y9axis-label {
/*    text-align: center;*/
    font-size: 11pt;
    margin-left: 10px;
    position: absolute;
}

.jqplot-meterGauge-tick {
    font-size: 0.75em;
    color: #999999;
}

.jqplot-meterGauge-label {
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #999999;
}

table.jqplot-table-legend {
    margin-top: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    margin-left: 12px;
    margin-right: 12px;
}

table.jqplot-table-legend, table.jqplot-cursor-legend {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 0.75em;
}

td.jqplot-table-legend {
    vertical-align:middle;
}

/*
These rules could be used instead of assigning
element styles and relying on js object properties.
*/

/*
td.jqplot-table-legend-swatch {
    padding-top: 0.5em;
    text-align: center;
}

tr.jqplot-table-legend:first td.jqplot-table-legend-swatch {
    padding-top: 0px;
}
*/

td.jqplot-seriesToggle:hover, td.jqplot-seriesToggle:active {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.jqplot-table-legend .jqplot-series-hidden {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

div.jqplot-table-legend-swatch-outline {
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    padding:1px;
}

div.jqplot-table-legend-swatch {
    width:0px;
    height:0px;
    border-top-width: 5px;
    border-bottom-width: 5px;
    border-left-width: 6px;
    border-right-width: 6px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-right-style: solid;
}

.jqplot-title {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

table.jqplot-cursor-tooltip {
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    font-size: 0.75em;
}


.jqplot-cursor-tooltip {
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: rgba(208,208,208,0.5);
    padding: 1px;
}

.jqplot-highlighter-tooltip, .jqplot-canvasOverlay-tooltip {
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: rgba(208,208,208,0.5);
    padding: 1px;
}

.jqplot-point-label {
    font-size: 0.75em;
    z-index: 2;
}

td.jqplot-cursor-legend-swatch {
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

div.jqplot-cursor-legend-swatch {
    width: 1.2em;
    height: 0.7em;
}

.jqplot-error {
/*   Styles added to the plot target container when there is an error go here.*/
    text-align: center;
}

.jqplot-error-message {
/*    Styling of the custom error message div goes here.*/
    position: relative;
    top: 46%;
    display: inline-block;
}

div.jqplot-bubble-label {
    font-size: 0.8em;
/*    background: rgba(90%, 90%, 90%, 0.15);*/
    padding-left: 2px;
    padding-right: 2px;
    color: rgb(20%, 20%, 20%);
}

div.jqplot-bubble-label.jqplot-bubble-label-highlight {
    background: rgba(90%, 90%, 90%, 0.7);
}

div.jqplot-noData-container {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(96%, 96%, 96%, 0.3);
}

</style>

</head>

<body id="b">

<button class="button">Load</button>
<div class="chart" id="chart0" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart1" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart2" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart3" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart4" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart5" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart6" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart7" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart8" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart9" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart10" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart11" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart12" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart13" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart14" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart15" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart16" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart17" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart18" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart19" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart20" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart21" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart22" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart23" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart24" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart25" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart26" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart27" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart28" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart29" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart30" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart31" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart32" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart33" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart34" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart35" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart36" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart37" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart38" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart39" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart40" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart41" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart42" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart43" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart44" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart45" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart46" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart47" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart48" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart49" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart50" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart51" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart52" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart53" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart54" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart55" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart56" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart57" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart58" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart59" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart60" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart61" style="width: 300px; height: 200px">2</div>
<div class="chart" id="chart62" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart63" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart64" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart65" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart66" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart67" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart68" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart69" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart70" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart71" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart72" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart73" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart74" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart75" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart76" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart77" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart78" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart79" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart80" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart81" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart82" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart83" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart84" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart85" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart86" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart87" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart88" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart89" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart90" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart91" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart92" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart93" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart94" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart95" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart96" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart97" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart98" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart99" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart100" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart101" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart102" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart103" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart104" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart105" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart106" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart107" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart108" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart109" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart110" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart111" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart112" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart113" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart114" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart115" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart116" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart117" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart118" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart119" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>
<div class="chart" id="chart120" style="width: 300px; height: 200px"></div>

</body>
<script>

var data = [[2.609466E7],[4272988.0],[999165.0],[123805.0]];
var label = ["Business Workstations","Home Desktops","Display Devices","Accessories"];
var colorsSpec = ['#fab818', '#c1e800', '#9ed927', '#00c2b4', '#33ccff', '#2bacf8', '#4c8ded', '#7079db', '#753374', '#e63262', '#f77a19', '#fedb00'];
jQuery('.button').click(function(){
  loadChart(1);
});
function loadChart(chartIndex){
  var size = jQuery('.chart').size();
  var targetDiv = 'chart' + chartIndex;
  generateStackedBarCharts(data, label, [''], targetDiv);
  if(chartIndex < size) {
    setTimeout(function(){loadChart(++chartIndex);});
  }
}
function generateStackedBarCharts(jsonDataObj, jsonLegendObj, jsonColsObj, targetDiv) {
  plot3 = $.jqplot(targetDiv, jsonDataObj, {
    // Only animate if we're not using excanvas (not in IE 7 or IE
    // 8)..
    animate: !$.jqplot.use_excanvas,
    animateReplot: !$.jqplot.use_excanvas,
    seriesColors: colorsSpec,
    // Tell the plot to stack the bars.
    stackSeries: true,
    captureRightClick: true,
    seriesDefaults: {
      renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
      rendererOptions: {
        // Put a 30 pixel margin between bars.
        barMargin: 30,
        // Highlight bars when mouse button pressed.
        // Disables default highlighting on mouse over.
        highlightMouseDown: true
      },
      pointLabels: {
        show: true,
        hideZeros: true,
        edgeTolerance: -5
      }
    },
    axes: {
      xaxis: {
        renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
        ticks: jsonColsObj,
        labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,
        tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
        tickOptions: {
          angle: -30,
          fontFamily: 'Arial',
          fontSize: '9pt'
        }
      },
      yaxis: {
        // Don't pad out the bottom of the data range. By default,
        // axes scaled as if data extended 10% above and below the
        // actual range to prevent data points right on grid
        // boundaries.
        // Don't want to do that here.
        padMin: 0,
        min: 0
      }
    },
    legend: {
      show: true,
      labels: jsonLegendObj,
      location: 'e',
      placement: 'outside'
    },
    cursor: {
      show: true,
      zoom: true,
      showTooltip: true,
      followMouse: true
    }
  });
}

</script>
</html>
```

**EDIT From Thang Pham**

In combine with this, you can call destroy() on jqplot object to release it to fix the issue with leaking memory. However since call destroy() on jqplot object will make the chart disappear, I convert the jqplot chart to image using

https://bitbucket.org/cleonello/jqplot/issue/14/export-capabilities#comment-554274

the method from the above link will return base64 image string, which to can feed to `<img>` using jQuery. Once that is done, you can safely call destroy() on jqplot object.

Comment: yeah, it hang (not responding) until it finish all the drawing and then all the plot show. sorry I was so busy with other task at hand, that I could not do jsfiddle, doing it now

Comment: Thank you, for some reason it works on the jsfiddle, but on the my system, it still attempt to draw all of them at once instead of drawing one by one like the example. so weird. Any more idea?

Comment: Try changing the timeout period from 1 to 100 milliseconds: `setTimeout(function(){createPlot(++plotIndex);},100);`. If the charts still draw all at the same time then recheck your code.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is but I've added a full working html for you to test.

Comment: Can you please attach jsfiddle.net/YX9wX/6 to your answer, I will award boundty after that. Thank you

Comment: Thanks! What do you mean by 'attach jsfiddle.net/YX9wX/6 to your answer'?

Comment: Ohh just want you have the link to the jsfiddle as part of your answer. It is easy for other to see the jsfiddle outcome.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps I misunderstood your question, but... you have some HTML div targets (20?):

```
<div id="targetDiv1"></div>
<div id="targetDiv2"></div>
<div id="targetDiv3"></div>
```

A common data (any):

```
var data = [[[1, 2], [3, 5.12], [5, 13.1], [7, 33.6], [9, 85.9], [11, 219.9]]];
```

One first plot in a div target with some concrete render options (say, blue color):

```
var barPlot = $.jqplot("targetDiv1", data, {series: [{color: "#0000ff"}]});
```

And then do you want to replot the same data in some different div targets with other render options?

If so, try to call the `init`method and then `replot`:

```
barPlot.init("targetDiv2", barPlot.data, {series: [{color: "#ff0000"}]});
barPlot.replot({clear: false});

barPlot.init("targetDiv3", barPlot.data, {series: [{color: "#ff00ff"}]});
barPlot.replot({clear: false});
```

Comment: ohh thanks. I will give it a try, and see if this will help me solve the memory problem in IE if I draw lots of graphs

Answer (score 1):

I would try a different approach.

Ok, IE hangs when you are creating 20 graphs, but other browsers hang also, but just shorter. 
If you are loading a lot of data in your graphs, all browsers will hang. It is also depending on the computer performance and specific plateforms like browsers on phones for example.

The best basic design pattern I know to load big content is to use a loading layer and load a page with big content using JQuery `load()` function. This function will hang your browser durring loading (synchrone mode), but a message with an image will be displayed for the user comprehension.

In your case, you could have a `div` `graphs-container` hidden by default in your web page, use a div to display a loading animation (or apply a loading layer by CSS class to your `graphs-container` visible by default in this case), then load your big page using JQuery `load()` function. In the success loading callback, you can hide the loading layer and reveal the loaded page, all the graphs in your case.

Usually, I compose the loading layer class with an animate gif wheel and a simple text.

To improve the rendering performance and save the user bandwidth, you can also compress web pages using [`PHP ob-gzhandler`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-gzhandler.php) or directly using `.htaccess` rules : http://www.xpertdeveloper.com/2012/04/htaccess-gzip-compression/

Another tip would be to load JS libs only once, JQPlot have a lot of plugins you are certainly using which take time to load.

Here is a possible implementation of a loading layer div to display a text with an animation durring the graphs-loading:

```
<!-- The loading layer with loading message and animated GIF -->
<div id='graphs-loading-layer' class='loading'>Loading in progress...</div>

<!-- The target div to load all your graphs -->    
<div id='graphs-container'></div>

<!-- Loading class example -->        
<style>
    .loading{   
        border:1px dotted black;
        font-size:25px;
        background-color:white;
        background-image:url(./loading.gif);
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-position:center center;
        opacity:0.6;
        z-index:200;
        width:99%;
        min-height:442px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        position:relative;
        text-align:center;
        line-height:300px;
    }
</style>

<script>
   //allJQPlotGraphs.php is the file (or a call to a controller in MVC model) where the graphs are generated
   $('#graphs-container').hide().load('allJQPlotGraphs.php',{/*JSON map data*/},function(){
      //Here is the success callback, fade out the loading layer div
      $('#graphs-loading-layer').fadeOut(300,function(){     
          //Then, display the graphs container with all graphs loaded
          $('#graphs-container').fadeIn(300);
      });      
   });
</script>
```